# UICollectionView custom cell UILabel missing when UIImageView has image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have problems using Custom UICollectionViewCell. Custom cell has one UILabel and one UIImageView. The problem is, when I put image on UIImageView(Left screenshot), UILabel in same cell disappears like picture below. But if there's no Image source on UIImageView, UILabel is not missing.

[image]

---

This is code for Viewcontroller which has UICollectionView

```
class CatTowerVeiwController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var popCountSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let switchState = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDataKey.popCountVisibility)
        popCountSwitch.setOn(switchState, animated: false)
        
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CatTowerCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        setupFlowLayout(numberOfCells: 2.0)
    }

    
    @IBAction func doneButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let isLabelVisible = self.popCountSwitch.isOn
        UserDefaults.standard.set(isLabelVisible, forKey: UserDataKey.popCountVisibility)
        
        
        self.dismiss(animated: false)
    
    }
}

extension CatTowerVeiwController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CatTowerCell
        
//        cell.cellImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "popcat_closed")
        cell.cellName.text = "Popcat"
        print(cell.cellName.frame.size.height)
        print(cell.cellName.frame.size.width)

        
        return cell
    }
    

}

extension CatTowerVeiwController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let leftAndRightPaddings: CGFloat = 45.0
        let numberOfItemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2.0
    
        let width = (collectionView.frame.width-leftAndRightPaddings)/numberOfItemsPerRow
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }
    
    
    private func setupFlowLayout(numberOfCells: CGFloat) {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)

        let halfWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / numberOfCells
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: halfWidth * 0.8 , height: halfWidth * 0.8)
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = halfWidth * 0.1
        
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
    }
}
```

And this is code for custom cell

```
class CatTowerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellName: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
}
```

---

This is what I trying to make:

[image]

Comment: What constraints do you have on the image and label? Did you set their content hugging/compression resistance priorities?

Comment: please check if you have used correct image name, is this image available in image assets?

Comment: Change the order of appearance with the label at frontmost.

Comment: as per @Sweeper says it's constraint issue. check your constraint or simply do assign imageview backgroud color and check. you will understood.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I checked image name is correct

Comment: @ElTomato Unfortunately, I tried changing order of those but nothing changed 

Comment: @DanChoi go to cell and remove all constraint than assign constraint like this imageview (Lead,Trail & Top) than assign lable (Lead,Trail,Bottom & Top(as bottom of image), Height= 15||18 ) than check

Comment: @Sweeper I changed compression resistance priority of UILabel and It's fixed

Comment: @RB's I found UILabel height became 0 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was  ***Compression Priority***

The height of UILabel became 0 because UIImageView is too big

My solution is setting Vertical compression Priority of UILabel larger than UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Pin your imageview's bottom anchor constraint to the label's top anchor.
And make sure there are no conflicting constraints.

```
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```